# What is the Biblical basis for born-again virginity?

Tags: biblical-basis, sexuality

The concept of being [born again as a virgin spiritually](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Born-again_virgin) (although physical virginity is no longer intact) has been a catchphrase I've noticed in the past few years. What is the Biblical basis for this trend? I would like to know if Jesus specifically had anything to say about this. From what I understand, He pardoned the sexual sins of Mary Magdalene, for example, but did not mention the need to be a born-again virgin, merely chaste from that point forward (not re-claiming virginity). If this does not come from the Bible, where did the idea for the need to be a born-again virgin originate?

Comment: Could you provide a link or two to people talking about this?

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Born-again_virgin
or do I need to put them in the body as an edit?

Comment: and a pop culture reference: http://www.eonline.com/news/504485/the-bachelor-s-sean-lowe-catherine-giudici-grilled-on-sex-life-born-again-virginity-in-lie-detector-test-watch-now

Answer (score 4):

### TL;DR

“Born-again virginity” or “second virginity” is not a concept that is
expounded by any of the Biblical authors. It is not formal doctrine,
nor is there any requirement in the Scriptures to become a virgin again.

## Idolatry = Adultery; Holiness = Virginity

Among the most prominent analogies of man's relationship to God in the
Old Testament prophets is that of marriage. The relationship that a
woman has to her husband is likened to the relationship that Israel was
to have with God. Israel was not to "prostitute" herself with other gods. (E.g. [Jer 2:20](http://www.biblestudytools.com/nas/jeremiah/2-20.html), [Ezek 23](http://www.biblestudytools.com/nas/ezekiel/23.html), [Hos 2:1-13](http://www.biblestudytools.com/nas/hosea/passage.aspx?q=hosea+2:1-13))

It is in this sense that virginity is primarily spoken about in the
Bible. Many times, a “virgin” is used synonymously with “unmarried
woman” because one was expected to be the other, but where virginity
(or the lack thereof) is discussed at any length, it largely has to do
with the relationship of a husband and wife or metaphorically with
Israel’s relationship with God (or the church’s relationship with
Jesus).

### Second Virginity

Second virginity is not likely to be a part of any group’s formal
doctrine, because it is not an idea that originates in the Bible.

I have only heard the concept addressed in the context of sexuality
regarding people who recognize that they’ve made mistakes sexually,
but want to return to the (spiritual and emotional, primarily, but
perhaps to a much lesser extent, physical) pristine and clean state of
innocence/virginity so that if/when they marry in the future, their
relationship with thier spouse will not be further hindered by the
sins of their past. Though it is impossible for someone to *actually*
regain their innocence, the idea is a call to return to appropriate
and healthy behavior (abstinence until marriage). In part, the idea is
probably meant to give some measure of hope in recovery for people who
have forsaken their sexual innocence but long to return to it for the
sake of their own integrity and as a “gift” to their future spouse.

I think this is an application of Christian concepts. I don’t know if
one could make a case for it being a *need* or *requirement*. I have
only heard it spoken of as if it were *desirable* for the sake of
having a healthy marriage in the future.

Comment: This has some good points but I think you're missing a few things. The related imagery is is actually much more poignant that you suggest—not only are believing sinners relationship to God painted using marriage imagery, but God's chosen people are described as "adulterous" and having "prostituted themselves", but part of God's work of sanctification is purifying them and giving them clean hearts. Given how many times those patterns are repeated in various contexts I don't think it would be a stretch to say there _is_ a Biblical basis for the idea (if not exactly for the pop-culture version).

Comment: In that we should return to holiness and purity, there definitely is a Biblical impulsion. God redeems his unfaithful bride (e.g. Hosea), but I don't see a direct link between that and a "second virginity." Like I said, it is at best an application of Christian principles.